# HTTP request made with curl work but doesn't work in Java

Tags: java, http

I'm working on a virtual machine A that needs to send an HTTP request to another virtual machine B to verify if B exists. If B exists, we are redirected from A to B and if it doesn't exist, we stay in A.

Both A and B work on Linux.

I have tested my HTTP request with the curl command, and it works.

This is the request:

```
curl --head https://12345.example.cloud/test/login
```

And this is the response:

```
HTTP/2 200
date: Fri, 16 Apr 2021 06:25:41 GMT
content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
content-length: 99068
server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
cache-control: no-store
pragma: no-cache
x-frame-options: deny
set-cookie: JSESSIONID=9B3B01EF5D1D2F76B8CFF99A0062D720; Path=/ewks; Secure; HttpOnly
content-language: en-US
```

When I try to make this request in my Java code, like this:

```
String hostname = "https://" + clientId +".example.cloud/test/login";
                URL url = new URL(hostname);
                HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                try {
                    con.getResponseCode();
                } catch (UnknownHostException uhe) {
                    resultat = String.format( applicationContext.getMessage( "login.wrong_customer", null, locale ), clientId );
                } finally {
                    con.disconnect();
                }
```

And finally the redirection like this:

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT);
                        response.setHeader("Location", "https://" + idClient +".example.cloud/test/login");
```

I'm always getting the same error which is:

```
15:43:40,555  193743946 ERROR - Login.doPost:112                                   | Error : No trusted certificate found
```

Does anyone know how to solve this one?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your Java code, but with your Java installation. The server is using a new (or unknown) certificate, and `curl` is either not validating the certificate, or is using up-to-date root certificates (likely from the OS). Java doesn't use the OS root certificates, but has it's own list, and your Java installation is too old to have the newer root certificates. Update Java, or at least update the root certificates used by Java.

Comment: *I have tested my HTTP request with the curl command, and it works.* - have you tested it from inside virtual machine "A"? VM-VM networking may have independent issues from VM-outside world networking.